# get_post_types doesn't work in plugin

Tags: custom-post-types, plugins, plugin-development

The dilemma is that get_post_types() inside the plugin I am creating. And from researching now all post types are not registered until "wp_loaded". However, "wp_loaded" is executed when all plugins are loaded.

All post types have yet to be registered, but I need them in my plugin. Is there a way to solve this problem? My custom post types are attached to init.

```
    class MyPlugin
    {

        public static function init() {
        self::load_plugin_textdomain();
        self::register_post_status();
        $pt = MyPlugin::get_post_types();
        //add a column for each post type here
        //add_action and add_filter
        }

        private static function get_post_types() 
        {
                return get_post_types( array( 'public' => true ), 'objects' );
        }

    }

add_action( 'init', create_function( '', 'return MyPlugin::init();' ) );
```

Comment: it's not clear what the problem is. your `get_post_types` code should be hooked to run after post types are created. add the code you have tried to your question.

Comment: I've added some code that gives the general approach of my plugin

Comment: you don't specify a priority on your action, so it will run in whatever position it gets placed in the queue, which may be before something else adds its init actions. if your goal is to ultimately modify the registered post types, theres already an action for that: `registered_post_type`.

Comment: @Milo registered_post_type does not include custom post types

Comment: `registered_post_type` action is triggered for all post types including custom types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you’ll be able to get all the post types that are registered on init. (other plugins may register extra post types)

Can't you hook into wp_loaded?